# Why does the print statement at the bottom of my main method not print anything?

Tags: python

I'm working on the MIT open courseware for CS-600 and I can't figure out why the last print statement isn't printing anything. Here's the code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
# 6.00 Problem Set 9
#
# Name:
# Collaborators:
# Time:

from string import *

class Shape(object):
    def area(self):
        raise AttributeException("Subclasses should override this method.")

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, h):
        """
        h: length of side of the square
        """
        self.side = float(h)
    def area(self):
        """
        Returns area of the square
        """
        return self.side**2
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Square with side ' + str(self.side)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Two squares are equal if they have the same dimension.
        other: object to check for equality
        """
        return type(other) == Square and self.side == other.side

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        """
        radius: radius of the circle
        """
        self.radius = float(radius)
    def area(self):
        """
        Returns approximate area of the circle
        """
        return 3.14159*(self.radius**2)
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Circle with radius ' + str(self.radius)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Two circles are equal if they have the same radius.
        other: object to check for equality
        """
        return type(other) == Circle and self.radius == other.radius

#
# Problem 1: Create the Triangle class
#
## TO DO: Implement the `Triangle` class, which also extends `Shape`.

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base = float(base)
        self.height = float(height)
    def area(self):
        return self.base*self.height/2
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Triangle with base ' + str(self.base) + 'and height ' + str(self.height)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) == Triangle and self.base == other.base and self.height == other.height
#
# Problem 2: Create the ShapeSet class
#
## TO DO: Fill in the following code skeleton according to the
##    specifications.

class ShapeSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize any needed variables
        """
        self.allCircles = []
        self.allSquares = []
        self.allTriangles = []
        self.allShapes = self.allCircles + self.allSquares + self.allTriangles
        self.place = None 
    def addShape(self, sh):
        """
        Add shape sh to the set; no two shapes in the set may be
        identical
        sh: shape to be added
        """
        if not isinstance(sh, Shape): raise TypeError('not a shape')
        if isinstance(sh, Square):
            for sq in self.allSquares:
                if sh == sq:
                    raise ValueError('shape already in the set')
            self.allSquares.append(sh)
        if isinstance(sh, Triangle):
            for tri in self.allTriangles:
                if sh == tri:
                    raise ValueError('shape already in the set')
            self.allTriangles.append(sh)
        if isinstance(sh, Circle):
            for circ in self.allCircles:
                if sh == circ:
                    raise ValueError('shape already in the set')
            self.allCircles.append(sh)
    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Return an iterator that allows you to iterate over the set of
        shapes, one shape at a time
        """
        self.place = 0
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.place >= len(self.allShapes):
            raise StopIteration
        self.place += 1
        return self.allShapes[self.place - 1]

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Return the string representation for a set, which consists of
        the string representation of each shape, categorized by type
        (circles, then squares, then triangles)
        """
        shapeList = ""
        for item in self.allShapes:
            shapeList += item.get__str__ + "br/"
        return shapeList

#
# Problem 3: Find the largest shapes in a ShapeSet
#
def findLargest(shapes):
    """
    Returns a tuple containing the elements of ShapeSet with the
       largest area.
    shapes: ShapeSet
    """
    ## TO DO

#
# Problem 4: Read shapes from a file into a ShapeSet
#
def readShapesFromFile(filename):
    """
    Retrieves shape information from the given file.
    Creates and returns a ShapeSet with the shapes found.
    filename: string
    """
    ## TO DO

def main():
    sq1 = Square(4.0)
    sq2 = Square(5.0)
    sq3 = Square(3.0)
    circ1 = Circle(3.0)
    circ2 = Circle(3.2)
    tri1 = Triangle(3.0, 4.0)
    tri2 = Triangle(4.0, 3.0)
    tri3 = Triangle(1.0, 1.0)
    thisSet = ShapeSet()
    thisSet.addShape(sq1)
    thisSet.addShape(sq2)
    thisSet.addShape(sq3)
    thisSet.addShape(circ1)
    thisSet.addShape(circ2)
    thisSet.addShape(tri1)
    thisSet.addShape(tri2)
    thisSet.addShape(tri3)
    print thisSet



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes allShapes an empty list:

```
self.allShapes = self.allCircles + self.allSquares + self.allTriangles
```

If you modify allCircles, that doesn't affect allShapes.  I would personally eliminate allShapes, and in the **str** method, add them at the last possible second:

```
for item in self.allCircles + self.allSquares + self.allTriangles:
```

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
self.allShapes = self.allCircles + self.allSquares + self.allTriangles
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  It sets `allShapes` to an empty list, and then as you add shapes later, nothing updates `allShapes`.

Then your `__str__` function just loops over `allShapes`, which is still empty, so your `__str__` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
self.allShapes = self.allCircles + self.allSquares + self.allTriangles
```

When you concatenate lists like this, the result is a *copy* of the component lists. So when those lists are changed later, the concatenated list isn't changed. In this case, `self.allCircles`, etc. are all empty. So `self.allShapes` is an empty list too; the for loop in `ShapeSet.__str__` doesn't append anything to `ShapeList`, and so the result is an empty string.

One simple way to fix this would be to make `allShapes` a *method* that you call, and that returns a new concatenation of `self.allCircles`... etc. each time it's called. That way, `allShapes` is always up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, then it must be because of

```
item.get__str__
```

which should raise an exception.

**Edit**: as others have noted, this isn't the actual problem, but I leave this here as a hint for further progress. Mind you, it's considered bad style ("unpythonic") to call `x.__str__()` directly, as you probably intended. Call `str(x)` instead, even in the implementation of `__str__`.

Answer (score 0):

You assign allShapes to be the *value* of self.allCircles + self.allSquares + self.allTriangles at the *start* in your init method (when the other lists are empty).

It's value is then never changed, so it remains empty.

You need this in addShape:

```
self.allShapes.append(sh)
```